# Uniform continuity in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: functional-analysis

I have trouble with this question:

**What does it mean that a function is uniformly continuous in a domain $D\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ ?**

I know the definition for uniform continuity , but im not sure if this is enough. Since our domain can be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ ?

Answer (score 2):

In the ordinary definition of uniform continuity, just use the norm of a vector instead of the absolute value to get the generalized notion of uniform continuity for a function defined on a domain in Euclidean space.  The point is that for two points at distance less than $\delta$ the difference in the value of the function should be less than $\epsilon$ where $\delta$ only depends on $\epsilon$ but not on the points (with the usual epsilon-delta preamble, of course).

Comment: So you mean that i replace our 2 points x and c with vectors x and c?

Comment: ∀ϵ>0,∃δ>0 s.t ||x||,||c||∈D and ||x−c||<δ⇒||f(x)−f(c)||<ϵ..
Like this? (I should have bars over x and c also, but dont know how to do that)

Comment: Yes, $x,c\in\mathbb{R}^n$ though I am a bit worried about the fact that you imply an asymmetry between the two points by denoting one by $x$ and the other by $c$ as if $c$ is more of a constant than $x$. Remember the whole point about uniform continuity is that neither of the points is preferred (uniform continuity is not a point-wise notion but rather a global notion).

Comment: Yes, your second comment is better.

Comment: Ah okay, so both x and c plays equally important roles in the definition? Is that what your saying?

Comment: Im also not sure of the real reason on why we are replacing x and c as vectors instead of points?

Comment: Think this through in the case of ordinary continuity first. We are not doing anything different here in that respect.  To define ordinary continuity at a point in Euclidean space you will also have to work with norm in place of absolute value.

Comment: Okay , it makes more sense now.

Comment: So the final definition should be in this style: ∀ϵ>0,∃δ>0 s.t ||x||,||c||∈D and ||x−c||<δ⇒||f(x)−f(c)||<ϵ
Where x and c should have bars above them ( to denote that they are vectors) ?

Comment: You should put parentheses around the two conditions before $\Rightarrow$. Otherwise the logical structure of the definition is not clear.

Comment: ∀ϵ>0, ∃δ>0 s.t ( ||x||,||c||∈D and ||x−c||<δ ) ⇒||f(x)−f(c)||<ϵ ?

Comment: Much better. To write a more detailed version, you could explicitly outfit both $x$ and $c$ by a universal quantifier, and then write the implication.